# running pytest does nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I created a python file for running pytest but whenever I run pytest nothing happens and command prompt stays as it is. But when I do Ctrl+C this following Traceback is printing. I couldn't find how to solve this issue. I will be grateful for any support you can provide.

````
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py", line 255, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\anyio\\__pycache__\\tmp7fewgyj8'        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pytest-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 187, in console_main
    code = main()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 145, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 324, in _prepareconfig
    config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 102, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config: Config = outcome.get_result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1016, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1304, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1187, in _preparse
    self.pluginmanager.load_setuptools_entrypoints("pytest11")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 287, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 86, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 163, in exec_module
    _write_pyc(state, co, source_stat, pyc)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 315, in _write_pyc
    with atomic_write(os.fspath(pyc), mode="wb", overwrite=True) as fp:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atomicwrites\__init__.py", line 166, in _open
    with get_fileobject(**self._open_kwargs) as f:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atomicwrites\__init__.py", line 183, in get_fileobject
    descriptor, name = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=suffix, prefix=prefix,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py", line 336, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py", line 255, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)```
````

Comment: did you try running it  as an admin (using `sudo`) ?

Comment: Actually, in the case of error logs completeness is appreciated. If anything, it would be helpful if you could show some actual code that reproduces the problem. But it sounds like this is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you dont have the right permissions as stated by @mrCopiCat, but you are on windows so you can do something like this.

```
import ctypes, sys

def elevate():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if elevate():
    # Put your program here
else:
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

Or better yet using `elevate`: https://pypi.org/project/elevate/